# plot a decision tree with python

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Hi I've found this code and I'm trying to plot a decision tree, but at the very end this "visualize_tree(test,columns)" give me an error: this is the code

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import subprocess

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz



y = test["churn"]
X = test[columns]
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
dt.fit(X, y)

def visualize_tree(tree, feature_names):
    """Create tree png using graphviz.

    Args
    ----
    tree -- scikit-learn DecsisionTree.
    feature_names -- list of feature names.
    """
    with open("dt.dot", 'w') as f:
        export_graphviz(tree, out_file=f,
                        feature_names=feature_names)

    command = ["dot", "-Tpng", "dt.dot", "-o", "dt.png"]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(command)
    except:
        exit("Could not run dot, ie graphviz, to "
             "produce visualization")



visualize_tree(test,columns)
```

As I said only the very last line give me an error:

```
In[471]: visualize_tree(test,columns)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-471-ccc62a7b61d9>", line 1, in <module>
    visualize_tree(test,columns)
  File "<ipython-input-470-be9bd10e9f84>", line 81, in visualize_tree
    feature_names=feature_names)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py", line 403, in export_graphviz
    recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0, criterion=decision_tree.criterion)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace?

Comment: done in the original message, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The docstring of `visualize_tree` states that the first argument should be an instance of `DecisionTreeClassifier`. So the correct way to call it is

```
visualize_tree(dt, columns)
```

and not

```
visualize_tree(test, columns)
```

because `test` (according to the stacktrace) is a `DataFrame`.

---

An update regarding the use of `exit`: I think the code intended to use [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which allows using an `str` argument. However, this fails as well if you're running IPython inside PyCharm (see this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19997)). Whay you could do instead is this:

```
sys.stderr.write("Could not run dot, ie graphviz, to produce visualization")
sys.exit(1)
```

The more important part is that the `visualize_tree` could only reach this statement if `subprocess.check_call` terminated with an exception. So make sure you have [Graphviz installed](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php).

Comment: in this case the error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-473-7bc69dfb3e19>", line 1, in <module>
    visualize_tree(dt, columns)
  File "<ipython-input-470-be9bd10e9f84>", line 86, in visualize_tree
    exit("Could not run dot, ie graphviz, to "
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Right, just change it to `sys.exit`.

The builtin `exit` (in IPython) does not accept any arguments.

Comment: do you mean: except:
        sys.exit("Could not run dot, ie graphviz, to "
             "produce visualization")       because it give error as well   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 260, in DoExit
    os._exit(args[0])
TypeError: an integer is required